# Mallet outputting either topic weight 0.0 or 1.0 and nothing in between

Tags: java, nlp, topic-modeling, mallet

So created a little program using mallet's API [following this example in the developer's guide](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/topics-devel.php). However, I do not understand the final weight output.

While the program is running it is outputting reasonable weights to each topic(see below):

```
Mallet LDA: 20 topics, 5 topic bits, 11111 topic mask
max tokens: 5179
total tokens: 31712
<10> LL/token: -7,88809
<20> LL/token: -7,54327
<30> LL/token: -7,44727
<40> LL/token: -7,3755

0   0,5 parses files browser creates selects docking entity 
1   0,5 boolean listener handles enabled directory mouse lines 
2   0,5 text area selected inserts creates deletes user 
3   0,5 int line offset caret screen moves end 
4   0,5 creates node container widget namespace block grid 
5   0,5 selection key event processes shows word start 
6   0,5 boolean search index indent hyper bundle dialog 
7   0,5 string element adds starts ends reader map 
8   0,5 handles changed message properties mode content loads 
9   0,5 creates fold plugin list marker model handler 
10  0,5 action set invokes edit creates char token 
11  0,5 pane option saves inits error save creates 
12  0,5 component adds size layout removes dockable window 
13  0,5 converts type view tostring rule parser closes 
14  0,5 buffer update updates handles status invalidates byte 
15  0,5 evals creates menu callstack eval inits document 
16  0,5 class manager path url bsh impl chunk 
17  0,5 handles variable expression color property primitive icon 
18  0,5 file creates vfs request literal parent runs 
19  0,5 string parse editor.getexpansion preferredlayoutsize(parent preprocesskeyevent startlinecomment getstringproperty 

[...]

0   0,07447 parses string files entity selected decl lists 
1   0,09965 handles boolean listener adds mouse enabled drag 
2   0,09124 text area selected selects user input int 
3   0,14501 int line offset screen start count end 
4   0,07821 node creates container widget closes namespace grid 
5   0,05882 key event selection processes viewer extends handles 
6   0,16431 boolean indent list index equals updates modifiers 
7   0,08873 element string starts ends adds document map 
8   0,14141 handles changed message properties mode content loads 
9   0,12078 fold creates plugin marker model handler list 
10  0,11112 action creates invokes edit set token stream 
11  0,11896 option pane inits saves view creates color 
12  0,11379 component layout size adds dockable window removes 
13  0,11022 string converts tostring type char marks segment 
14  0,10636 buffer update handles updates byte status edit 
15  0,11183 evals creates menu callstack error eval reader 
16  0,09098 class path url manager impl classes loader 
17  0,09077 handles variable expression property creates bsh primitive 
18  0,12605 file string search vfs dialog creates literal 
19  0,02491 string parse setvalueat disposedockablewindow getpreviousbuffer buffered rewinds 

[beta: 0,02113] 
<500> LL/token: -6,90397

Total time: 16 seconds
```

However, when it comes to the final output this comes out:

```
0   0.000   parses (115) string (90) files (53) entity (33) selected (29) 
1   0.000   handles (110) boolean (82) listener (71) mouse (48) adds (44) 
2   0.000   text (230) area (126) selected (61) user (28) selects (27) 
3   0.000   int (588) line (295) offset (67) screen (54) start (49) 
4   0.000   node (71) creates (48) widget (34) closes (33) container (32) 
5   0.000   key (130) event (110) selection (81) processes (67) viewer (17) 
6   0.000   boolean (586) indent (55) index (51) list (51) updates (23) 
7   0.000   element (99) string (76) starts (48) ends (46) adds (43) 
8   0.000   handles (464) changed (153) message (150) properties (96) mode (96) 
9   0.000   fold (108) creates (107) plugin (97) marker (56) model (55) 
10  0.000   action (132) creates (89) invokes (64) set (61) edit (58) 
11  0.000   option (119) pane (118) inits (114) saves (77) view (68) 
12  0.000   component (128) adds (89) layout (87) size (76) dockable (63) 
13  0.000   string (488) converts (114) tostring (65) type (41) char (30) 
14  0.000   buffer (289) update (89) handles (71) updates (49) byte (30) 
15  0.000   evals (157) creates (121) menu (102) callstack (92) error (66) 
16  0.000   class (243) path (76) url (47) manager (42) impl (28) 
17  0.000   handles (134) variable (79) expression (73) creates (47) property (46) 
18  0.000   file (126) string (111) search (89) vfs (64) int (52) 
19  1.000   string (2705) parse (2605) parser.reinittokeninput(in (1) image (1) candidates[i (1) 
0   0.930564405720232
```

All the weights are marked as 0 except for that is marked as one. Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you're pointing to is printing out the topic distribution for the first document, which is almost 100% allocated to topic 19.

It looks like the collection is very small (30k words) and the documents are rather large (up to 5k). If there are more topics than documents, the model can maximize its objective by putting each document in its own topic.

You will get better results from more documents, and may need to consider breaking documents into smaller chunks. LDA works best when each segment is short enough that it could reasonably be assumed to have a homogenous mix of themes. In other words, you wouldn't expect the beginning of the segment to be about something different than the end of the segment. 200-500 words is a typical range. 300,000 total tokens is also probably about the minimum that you could expect good results.

Comment: Yeah, this was it. I was at first putting everything into a single document just to test. Going to separate by paragraph now.